# populate listbox with sql query result

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to build a sql query which will run a stored procedure. I then need the result of this query to appear in a listbox from which a user can select the desired result.

Please could someone show me how to construct the SQL query from scratch first of all, then show me how to get this result into a listbox?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can separate your tasks in multiple little tasks, and search for each one of them how to do it. Your task is pretty common and you will have every element to do it by searching just a bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillData();
        }

        void FillData()
        {
            var connString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                c.Open();

                // use a SqlAdapter to execute the query
                using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", c))
                {            
                    // fill a data table
                    var t = new DataTable();
                    a.Fill(t);

                    // Bind the table to the list box
                    listBox1.DisplayMember = "NameOfColumnToBeDisplayed";
                    listBox1.ValueMember = "NameOfColumnToUseValueFrom";
                    listBox1.DataSource = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: It directly answers the question with an example.

Comment: I disagree, [See this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) `•barely more than a link to an external site`

Comment: I dont see `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` for my ListBox control in C# code-behind.

Comment: Si8: the example is for winform, you might be using wpf

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general idea...

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
string connectionString = "your connection string here";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT column FROM myitemstable";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                lb.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)reader["column"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution but get the error on the lb. line saying listitem could not be found.